# How to get a list of all Webhooks in a discord server with DiscordPY

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Am i able to get a list of all webhook URLs in a discord server using discord.py or another Discord bot python library? Sorry that this is so short im not sure what other information i could provide for my question.

I have also tried the following.

```
import discord

client = command.Bot()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("webhook"):
        async def urls(ctx):
            @client.command()
            async def urls(ctx):
                content = "\n".join([f"{w.name} - {w.url}" for w in await ctx.guild.webhooks()])
                await ctx.send(content)

client.run('tokennumber')
```

Comment: Maybe the webhook documentation has a solution to your question: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#webhook-support

Comment: @merive_ I checked, however i couldn't find anything involving getting the webhook URL. if you can find anything regarding retrieving the URL or creating one then getting the URL, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example command using list comprehension that would return the link for each webhook:

```py
@bot.command()
async def urls(ctx):
    content = "\n".join([f"{w.name} - {w.url}" for w in await ctx.guild.webhooks()])
    await ctx.send(content)
```

Here's what the list comprehension is doing:

```py
@bot.command()
async def urls(ctx):
    wlist = []
    for w in await ctx.guild.webhooks():
        wlist.append(f"{w.name} - {w.url}")
    content = "\n".join(wlist)
    await ctx.send(content)
```

---

**Post-edit:**
Using your `on_message()` event:

```py
import discord

client = commands.Bot() # add command_prefix kwarg if you plan on using cmd decorators

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("webhook"):
        content = "\n".join([f"{w.name} - {w.url}" for w in await message.guild.webhooks()])
        await message.channel.send(content)

client.run('token')
```

If you don't want to print out each webhooks' name, then you can just join each url instead:

```py
content = "\n".join([w.url for w in await message.guild.webhooks()])
```

---

**References:**

- [List comprehension in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
- [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) - Python 3.6.0+
- [`Guild.webhooks()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.webhooks) - `coroutine`, therefore needs to be `await`ed.
- [`Webhook.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.name)
- [`Webhook.url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.url)

Comment: So should i use the code at the top or the code at the bottom? and when i tried the code it gave me the error "name 'bot' is not defined" How should i incorporate this into my bot?

Comment: They both do exactly the same thing. As for the error, it could be that your bot instance is called `client` instead, so just replace `bot` with `client` or whatever you called it. @EchoTheAlpha

Comment: I replaced `Bot` with `Client` and i got this error  ` 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' `

EDIT: Do you think i imported the wrong thing? the import i used is `Import discord`

EDIT2: I use this `client = discord.Client()`

Comment: Try using `client = commands.Bot()` instead. It inherits from `discord.Client()` and is capable of much more.

Comment: I got another error,  `client = command.Bot() NameError: name 'command' is not defined`
EDIT: I am going to edit my question to show what my script fully looks like.

Comment: Sorry for the slow replies! Edited the answer ^

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, and thank you for sticking with me. However, i am getting another error message. `client = commands.Bot("<") NameError: name 'commands' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, I keep missing out important things from the answer! Make sure you have `from discord.ext import commands` at the top of your code.

Comment: This worked really well, and i saved it to a file using the Pickle library, and copy and pasted the urls into a script that saves them as a file and they were both the same, meaning that it does in fact get all of the URLs. Thank you for sticking with me even when i was confused.

Comment: No worries! Tomorrow I'll edit the answer a bit more to explain everything, but for now I'll be sleeping. G'night, and good luck with the bot :^)

Comment: Goodnight, and when you wake up, could you tell me how to remove the name of the URL? as currently, the URLs have the name of them. When i print them they say the following. `webhookname - urlthing`

Comment: Hello, I know i am asking a lot, but i was wondering if it was possible to get the URLs into an array, and i found out how to remove the name, i just removed the `w.name` variable, but maybe if you can find the amount of webhooks, and if you can find individual URLs, maybe you can loop over and `append` the webhooks to an array. I'm not sure if this would work, i'm just trying to give ideas. Thanks, again.

Comment: `await ctx.guild.webhooks()` returns a list. You can extract a list of specific attributes with a list comprehension, such as `webhook_urls = [w.url for w in await ctx.guild.webhooks()]`

Comment: I tried what you said, and it said `name 'ctx' is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215536/discussion-between-diggy-and-echothealpha).